# Wordpress - plugin custom template is always shows "blog" on the breadcrumbs

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, templates

UPDATE*****

I found why the plugin was loading on top of the blog. I needed the following added to the load_main function

```
public function load_main(){
$dir = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ );        
include ($dir.'/templates/main.php');   
exit();
}
```

However, I am still trying to figure out why the breadcrumbs shows as Home-> Blog.

Do I need to create a custom Taxonomy and post type for my custom template?  If so, how do I apply it to the template for the breadcrumbs.

Any help would be appreciated.

ORIGINAL POST****

I have created a rewrite rule to route to a custom template.  When I activate my plugin, the rewrite rule is being applied, but when I navigate to the permalink I get the custom template loaded on top of the "blog" page.  Meaning at the top of my page, I see the main.php template I created followed by a list of all my blog posts.

The breadcrumbs show that the permalink navigated to the "Blog" menu item.  Here is the code I am using for my rewrite_rules and to load the custom template.

```
class ssa_tools {
public function __construct(){
    register_activation_hook(__FILE__, array($this,'flush_application_rewrite_rules'));
    add_action('template_redirect', array($this,'front_controller'));
    add_action('ssa_main', array($this,'load_main'));
    add_filter('query_vars', array($this, 'manage_user_routes_query_vars'));

} 
public function manage_user_routes() {
    add_rewrite_rule( '^ssa_tools/([^/]+)/?','index.php?control_action=$matches[1]', 'top' );
}
public function manage_user_routes_query_vars($query_vars){
    $query_vars[] = 'control_action';
    return $query_vars;
}
public function flush_application_rewrite_rules() {
    $this->manage_user_routes();
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
public function front_controller(){
    global $wp_query;
    $control_action = isset ( $wp_query->query_vars['control_action'] ) ? $wp_query->query_vars['control_action'] : '';

    switch ($control_action) {
        case 'ssa_main':
            do_action('ssa_main');
            break;
}
public function load_main(){
    $dir = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ );     
    include ($dir.'/templates/main.php');       
}
}
```

The URL I am using is ssa.dev/ssa_tools/ssa_main/ on a local machine. It seems like routing is occuring twice, once for my template then routing to the "blog" page.  Again, when I look at the breadcrumbs it shows home->blog.

Any suggestions or help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The theme I was using (thrive themes) had coding that applied a default of "blog" to the breadcrumbs.  Since the custom plugin I created generated its own template pages, the theme was causing the default.

To resolve, I added a child theme and rewrote the breadcrumb code as was needed.